# How to manually close connection in BaseHTTPServer?

Tags: python, sockets, basehttpserver

I have a script that sends a request to an HTTP server.

HTTP server script (snippet):

```
...

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(sa):
    pdict = cgi.parse_header(sa.headers.getheader('referer'))
    q = pdict[0]
    q = urllib.unquote(q)

    if q == "enternetixplorer" # basically just ignore this, doesn't have to do with the question
      sa.wfile.write("blah blah blah")
      # now restart server
      httpd.server_close()
      python = sys.executable
      os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

...
```

The "blah blah blah" is sent back, but the connection does not seem to close, and my script is waiting forever until I abort the server. (My thought is BaseHTTPServer automatically closes connection when the last part in "do_GET()" is computed, but I prevent this by restarting the script.)

If I'm right, how do I close the connection? If not, what else might be the problem?

Edit:
The server script HAS to restart the entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute:

```
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

The Python [documentation for os.exec*](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execl) says this:

> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current
>   process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded
>   into the current process, and will have the same process id as the
>   caller. Errors will be reported as OSError exceptions.

So, when you call that function, the `do_GET` function hangs and never returns, so the HTTP server never flushes the end of the HTTP message.

I think in your case, the easiest change is to call [os.fork](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fork) before calling exec, then call exec only in the child process. Let the parent process return from the do_GET function.